# Low Variables Error : "Field 'edit_date' doesn't have a default value"

Tags: low-variables

I've had this happen on a couple of different projects today. Weird coincidence? Something I'm doing?

The error shows up upon trying to save a new variable. The variable does actually get created, but only the Variable Name is saved.

Anyone seen this error before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because of MySQL running in Strict mode and only if LV was installed before version 2.3.3. You can work around it by setting a default value of 0 on the edit_date column in the exp_low_variables table.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I also found this resource for disabling "strict mode": http://cameronspear.com/blog/homebrew-and-mysql-strict-mode/